# Azure B2C How to prevent more than one password change per day

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am using B2C custom polices and I would like to prevent a user from changing their password more than once per day. Is it possible to get the date of the last password change and do this check in a custom policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this policy which uses the concept of storing a dateTime on the user object to do some conditional control:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days

and
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-absolute-timeout-and-ip-change-trigger

You can store the date on the user object extension attribute upon successful password change. Then when the user tries to reset the password, check this timestamp and compare to 24hrs using a claimsTransform. Store a boolean result in a claim. This can be done using an orchestration step that is of type [claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) which calls a [dateComparison transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/date-transformations#datetimecomparison).

You can do this calculation and set a claim value before the self asserted technical profile which shows the password reset screen. Then after the user verifies their email you can use an output claims transform to make sure this [boolean is false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue), and otherwise throw an error using the metadata item as shwon below in the self asserted technical profile where you collect the email:

```xml
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Custom error message if account is disabled.</Item>
  </Metadata>
```